# PHP Insert multiple rows in split batches

Tags: php, mysql, insert, split

I have a query to insert multiple rows in split batches. Basically, I need to split inserts in batches so that I can generate a unique random ID to the inserted batch.

What I've tried and failed with many different options, one of them as follow.

```
$batch = 150;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table` GROUP BY `column` ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
$sqle = $con->Execute($sql);
$results = $sqle->getrows();
for($i=0; $i<count($results);$i++){
    $columns1 = $results[$i]['column'];
      if($i==$batch){
            $randd = randcode(5).time();
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `newtable` SET `columns1` = ".$con->qstr($columns1).", `rcode` = ".$con->qstr($randd).", `DATE_PUBLISHED` = ".$con->qstr($sdate);
                $results=$con->Execute($sql);
           $i=0;
        }
}
```

However, am not successful in inserting unique code to every 150 batch inserted query.

Where am I going wrong in generating random unique code for every batch? And also I would like to know if there is less than 150 records, then how to handle the same?

Comment: Your INSERT query is seems to be wrong

Comment: Yes this query looping infinitely

Comment: Just to see if i follow correctly; You want the unique code to be unique per inserted batch of rows, not per single inserted row? E.g. for the first 150 inserted rows it could be "12345" and for the next 150 rows it could be "56789"?

Comment: `$results` is used in the `for` loop's condition, but inside the loop it's manipulated (so it will probably never stop running?). Maybe it's better to choose another name?

Comment: @mhall yes exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will provide you with the logic for a basic way for setting a random ID per batch.

In this example, there is no database connectivity. You will have to add that yourself. You also want to have a look at the syntax for the [INSERT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) statement (spoiler: `INSERT INTO <table name> (<columns>) VALUES (<values>)`).

```
// For this example, generate a result array with 350 rows
// (remove when using actual db query)
for ($i = 1; $i <= 350; $i++) {
    $results[] = ['column' => 'column ' . $i];
}

// Loop through all result rows
foreach ($results as $batchCounter => $result) {
    if ($batchCounter % 150 == 0) {
        // Generate a new random ID for the first row and every 150 rows
        $random = uniqid();
    }

    // Replace with proper insert statement
    echo "Insert random ", $random, ' for column "', $result['column'], '"', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Insert random 55e0186b0607f for column "column 1"
Insert random 55e0186b0607f for column "column 2"
Insert random 55e0186b0607f for column "column 3"
...
Insert random 55e0186b0607f for column "column 150"
Insert random 55e0186b063da for column "column 151"
Insert random 55e0186b063da for column "column 152"
Insert random 55e0186b063da for column "column 153"
...
Insert random 55e0186b063da for column "column 300"
Insert random 55e0186b0666e for column "column 301"
Insert random 55e0186b0666e for column "column 302"
Insert random 55e0186b0666e for column "column 303"
...
Insert random 55e0186b0666e for column "column 350"
```

Comment: this is somewhat close, am just not able to insert other column with right values, will update as I get results, thanks

Comment: If you are using [ADOdb](http://phplens.com/adodb/), you may want to check out their [insert tutorial](http://phplens.com/adodb/tutorial.inserting.html)

Comment: perfectly worked like a charm, thanks so much for all your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this one

```
<?php

$batch = 0;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table` GROUP BY `column` ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
$sqle = $con->Execute($sql);
$results = $sqle->getrows();


$sql = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($results);$i++)
{
    $columns1 = $results[$i]['column'];
    $randd = randcode(5).time();

    if($batch==0)
    {
        $sql = "insert into `demo` (`columns1`, `rcode`, `DATE_PUBLISHED`) values "
    }

    $sql.= "(".$results[$i]['column1'].",".$randd.",".$results[$i]['column1']."),";

    if($batch==150)
    {       
        $results=$con->Execute($sql);
        $batch=0;
        $sql="";
    }
    $batch++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work, though I fixed some errors from your code, but still insert was successful with just 1 insert.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this one. I fixed some errors from your code to insert records successfully:

```
<?php

$batch = 1;
$rows = 0;
$sql = "";
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table` GROUP BY `column` ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
$sqle = $con->Execute($sql);
$results = $sqle->getrows();

for($i=0; $i<count($results);$i++)
{
    $columns1 = $results[$i]['column'];
    $randd = randcode(5).time();

    if($batch==1)
    {
        $sql = "insert into `demo` (`columns1`, `rcode`, `DATE_PUBLISHED`) values "
    }

    $sql.= "(".$results[$i]['column1'].",".$randd.",".$results[$i]['column1']."),";

    $rows++;
    if($batch==100)
    {

        $this->SendRecords($conn, $sql);
        $batch=1;
        $sql="";
    } else if($rows == count($results) && $batch > 1 && $batch<=100){

        $this->SendRecords($conn, $sql);
        $batch=0;
        $sql="";
     }else {
        $batch++;
        $sql.=",";
    }
}
```